# Can't Add Primary key of one table in to another table using MVC Model

Tags: mysql, database, model-view-controller, primary-key

I have 3 tables Which are

1. Company Table  with primary key CompanyId
2. Sensor Table with primary key SensorId
3. Device Table with primary key DeviceId and foreign key with Companyid from company table and Sensorid from sensor table.

I can perform CRUD opertion in my Company and Sensor table.
But problem  is when I am trying to perform Insertion in device in give me the error.
Here is image of my error.

[image: Image of Error]

I stuck in this error .

Edited:

Solution:
I was writing the column name which are not in table ,
that's why It give me error.

Comment: A lot of images and less of relevant info. There is no way to understand what data you’re trying to insert from what you have given us. Have you tried to debug to see what is happening in `AddDeviceInfo`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for your kind advice. I found my mistake and I solve my problem. my mistake is that I am trying to insert foreign key value in device table which not in company  table